# How to have script fill out form after webpage opened?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, microsoft-edge

I am writing a script that fills out and submits an online form. The thing is the form is only available after I log in. How can I make it so that the script takes control of the Edge window that I have already used to login, and not start a new one up?

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium automates browser testing, including form login, button presses, filling in fields, and more. Selenium uses different WebDrivers for each browser you want to test; you can find the Edge WebDriver at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49962.

Hope this addresses your concern! You can find more information on Selenium at http://www.seleniumhq.org/.

Sources:

- Personal testing of Selenium with Edge browser in Visual Studio Community 2015, Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

IIUYC, you want to activate existing browser window using autohotkey. One way to do this is to get process id of the browser and make it active using `WinActivate`. More [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm). Example:

```
Processname=MicrosoftEdge.exe
Process, Exist, %Processname%

If !ErrorLevel
{
   MsgBox, % "Process " Processname " does not exist"
   return
}

pid := ErrorLevel
IfWinNotActive, % "ahk_pid " pid
{
WinActivate, % "ahk_pid " pid
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing much more information, you could try using one of the following libraries:

- Selenium: Good for use with .Net, Java, Ruby, and/or Python
- PhantomJS: Headless webkit used to allow browser automation to occur in the background.
- SlimerJS: Similar to PhantomJS however it is not natively headless. This is because Slimer is built on Gecko (which requires a graphical window).